# Fail to compile second time I run C++

Tags: c++

I a'm trying to to save some data for later use in a .txt file. The first time i run the code, no problem. The second time, all hell breaks loose. The function I you to write into the file is as following:

```
void VideoSelection::write(char Name[255], char address[255])
{
    int i = 0;
    string iString;
    saveFile.open("Movies.txt");
    for (string line; getline(input, line); ) // check for the number of movies (0-index)
    {
        iString = to_string(i);
        if (line == iString)
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
    saveFile << i << endl;
    saveFile << "NAME: " << Name << "   " << "ADDRESS: " << address << endl << endl;
    saveFile.close();
}
```

and the header file used is as following:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include "Movies.txt";

using namespace std;

class VideoSelection
{
public:
    VideoSelection();
    void write(char Name[255], char address[255]);
    void read();
    void sort();
    void open();
    ~VideoSelection();

protected:
    char http[255];
    ofstream saveFile;
    ifstream input;
};
```

and the main:

```
#include "VideoSelection.h"

int main()
{
    VideoSelection VS;
    char movieName[255];
    char movieAddress[255];
    cin >> movieName;
    cin >> movieAddress;

    VS.write(movieName, movieAddress);
}
```

These are the errors I'm getting

https://gyazo.com/f5f13e7dfd18378152df6126b7a40be1

Comment: What is this: **#include "Movies.txt";**

Comment: Remove #include "Movies.txt";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always start with the first error. (unexpected preprocessor token on line 6)

```
#include "Movies.txt";
```

Remove the semicolon such that it's

```
#include "Movies.txt"
```

But wait - why are you including a **non-code** TEXT file as a pre-processor directive?  That's probably what the second error message is about.  :)

I suspect you just need to remove that line completely.

Another side note:

```
using namespace std;
```

Try not to do a `using namespace` directive in a header file.  Only in the .cpp files. formally declare your stream members in that class as follows:

```
std::ofstream saveFile;
std::ifstream input;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a text file as pre-processor directive. The compiler is looking at the .txt file and analyze it as if it was a code file, and scream at what it looks as syntax errors.